# How to obtain the number of points, with integer coordinates of a regular figure?

Tags: geometry

If I have any figure, I'll choose a regular figure like this triangle:

This triangle, have 3 vertex: $A = (2, 2), B = (6, 2), C = (2, 4)$

Within this figure (including its edges), there are many points. So I was wondering how I can get all points with whole coordinates, within any regular figure?

In this triangle, I could do it one by one,

$ (2, 2) - (3, 2) - (4, 2) - (5, 2) - (6, 2) $

$ (2, 3) - (3, 3) - (4, 3) $

$ (2, 4) $

= 9 points

This would be extremely slow. I had thought that to get all the integer points of a figure, I can imagine all the squares of (1 x 1), which are inside the figure and count their vertices, but this would also be slow, since if it is a very large figure , I will have many squares and many more vertices. So, according to my thinking, the problem could be reduced to:
How many squares of (1, 1) are inside a figure? (The squares should have the 4 vertices inside the figure)

I did not write this as a title, because I do not know if this is correct.

[image: Triangle]

Here I check, if it works to count vertices, i get the same points ( 9 )

[image]

Comment: Do you want a list of the points or how many there are?  How many there are can come using Pick's theorem and counting the number on the boundary.

Comment: I want how many there are

Answer (score 1):

The first tool is [Pick's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pick%27s_theorem), which says the sum of the number of lattice points inside and half the number of lattice points on the boundary is the area of your figure.  You can evaluate the area of your figure by breaking it into triangles and adding up the areas.  Now we just have to compute the number of points on the boundary so we can add half that in again and we are there.

If one of your sides is from $(a,b)$ to $(c,d)$ you should compute $\gcd(c-a,d-b)$  The side will go through $\gcd(c-a,d-b)-1$ lattice points excluding the vertices.  For example, if your side runs from $(1,2)$ to $(10,14)$ it runs through $(4,6)$ and $(7,10)$.  If you count the ending vertex but not the starting one you get $\gcd(c-a,d-b)$ for each side.  Add those up for all the sides, divide by $2$, add to the area, and you have the number of lattice points in or on your figure.